# Ajustar el alto y el ancho máximo en gridster.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Estoy usando la librería [Gridster](https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) para realizar un drag and drop, el caso es que la pantalla tiene que tener límite en alto y en ancho, he estado tratando de limitarlo añadiendo un máximo de columnas y filas pero sigue aumentando sin fin al arrastrar.

¿Es un problema de la librería?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
    gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
      widget_base_dimensions: [50, 50],
      widget_margins: [5, 5],
      shift_widgets_up: false,
      shift_larger_widgets_down: true,
      min_cols: 10,
      max_cols: 20,
      max_size_x: 20,
      min_rows: 10,
      resize: {
        enabled: true,
        max_size: [4, 4],
        min_size: [1, 1]
      }
    }).data('gridster');
  });        
});
```

```css
/*! gridster.js - v0.7.0 - 2017-03-27 - * https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/ - Copyright (c) 2017 ducksboard; Licensed MIT */
.gridster {
    position: relative
}

.gridster > * {
    -webkit-transition: height .4s,width .4s;
    -moz-transition: height .4s,width .4s;
    -o-transition: height .4s,width .4s;
    -ms-transition: height .4s,width .4s;
    transition: height .4s,width .4s
}

.gridster .gs-w {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    background: #61A9CF;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    list-style-type: none
}

.gridster .preview-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
    opacity: .3
}

.gridster .player-revert {
    z-index: 10 !important;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s,top .3s !important;
    -moz-transition: left .3s,top .3s !important;
    -o-transition: left .3s,top .3s !important;
    transition: left .3s,top .3s !important
}

.gridster.collapsed {
    height: auto !important
}

.gridster.collapsed .gs-w {
    position: static !important;
}

.ready .gs-w:not(.preview-holder), .ready .resize-preview-holder {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s,left .3s,top .3s,width .3s,height .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s,left .3s,top .3s,width .3s,height .3s;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s,left .3s,top .3s,width .3s,height .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s,left .3s,top .3s,width .3s,height .3s
}

.gridster .dragging, .gridster .resizing {
    z-index: 10 !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0s !important;
    -o-transition: all 0s !important;
    transition: all 0s !important
}

.gs-resize-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1
}

.gs-resize-handle-both {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: se-resize;
    z-index: 20
}

.gs-resize-handle-x {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 13px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 10px;
    cursor: e-resize
}

.gs-resize-handle-y {
    left: 0;
    right: 13px;
    bottom: -5px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: s-resize
}

.gs-w:hover .gs-resize-handle, .resizing .gs-resize-handle {
    opacity: 1
}

.gs-resize-handle, .gs-w.dragging .gs-resize-handle {
    opacity: 0
}

.gs-resize-disabled .gs-resize-handle, [data-max-sizex="1"] .gs-resize-handle-x, [data-max-sizey="1"] .gs-resize-handle-y, [data-max-sizey="1"][data-max-sizex="1"] .gs-resize-handle {
    display: none !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/dist/jquery.gridster.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="gridster">
      <ul id="lista" class="task-card-list" style="background-color: #337ab7;">
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Como se puede apreciar, si arrastras hasta el limite, el objeto se queda ahi, pero es posible forzarlo con una segunda pieza y superar el limite.

Comment: Si por ejemplo usas `max_cols: 6,` ya el usuario no puede extender la longitud del grid horizontalmente.

Comment: @FranAcuna si pero el problema de esta librería es que se puede forzar a salir del maximo vertical, si pones en el maximo un cuadrado y colocas otro en su posicion, para liberarlo lo baja, entonces de esta manera se puede superar el maximo. Lo estuve viendo y es un bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema proviene de la librería, como se puede apreciar en la imagen, al arrastrar un cuadrado el otro item baja hasta superar el limite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La mejor solución es buscar otra librería o construirlo por ti mismo, otra librería que puede ser útil es [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) o [Dragabilly](https://draggabilly.desandro.com/).

También puedes realizarlo por ti mismo usando [draggable](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable).

En mi caso he usado un conjunto para realizar la misma función, dejo mi [prueba](https://codepen.io/DonKaoz/pen/RwKGRbd) para problemas similares.